# Creating header row for DGW with Tablelayoutpanel

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, tablelayoutpanel

I have a tablelayoutpanel and below that is a datagridview with 9 columns. What I want to achieve is to create 7 cells (or columns) in the tablelayoutpanel. I want the first cell (or column) in the tablelayoutpanel to span the first three columns of the datagridview and then the next 6 columns (in the tablelayoutpanel) to be aligned with the other 6 columns in the datagridview. Beneath is a picture to demonstrate the end result:

[image]

Here is my code so far. As you can see I havent very gotten far. I am just wondering if this easily done? If so can someone edit my code to get it working? Is this even possible considering the window will be resizable? The project is created in winforms.

```
    public void SetDummyData()
    {
        var data = GetDummyData();
        var binding = new BindingSource { DataSource = data };           
        dataGridView1.DataSource = binding;
    }

    public List<TestData> GetDummyData()
    {
        return new List<TestData>()
        {
            new TestData { D1 = "", D2 = "", D3 = "", D4 = "", D5 = "", D6 = "", D7 = "", D8 = "", D9 = "" },
            new TestData { D1 = "", D2 = "", D3 = "", D4 = "", D5 = "", D6 = "", D7 = "", D8 = "", D9 = "" },
            new TestData { D1 = "", D2 = "", D3 = "", D4 = "", D5 = "", D6 = "", D7 = "", D8 = "", D9 = "" },
            new TestData { D1 = "", D2 = "", D3 = "", D4 = "", D5 = "", D6 = "", D7 = "", D8 = "", D9 = "" },
        };
    }

    public void SetTableLayout()
    {
        EmptyTable();
        tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 7;
        tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 1;
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn c in dataGridView1.Columns)
        {
            var percentage = GetDGWColumnPercentage(c);
            // Cant add percentage here?
            tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(percentage));
            // Then add label
        }
    }

    public void EmptyTable()
    {
        for (int i = tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls[i].Dispose();
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();
        tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 0;
    }

    public double GetDGWColumnPercentage(DataGridViewColumn c)
    {
        return (c.Width * 100) / dataGridView1.Width;
    }
```

Comment: First I recommend throwing away the tablelayoutpanel.  Instead create a main panel and add your own child panels to the main panel.  This will make it easier to set the widths of the object.  the all you will need to do is to set the column widths of the DGV to align with the widths of the panels.

Answer (score 0):

The numbers are approximate to give you an idea of how to do this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication71
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Panel panel1 = new Panel();
            panel1.Top = 100;
            panel1.Left = 100;
            panel1.Width = 600;
            panel1.Height = 100;
            panel1.BackColor = Color.Blue;
            this.Controls.Add(panel1);
            Panel panel2 = new Panel();
            panel2.Top = 10;
            panel2.Left = 20;
            panel2.Width = 180;
            panel2.Height = 80;
            panel2.BackColor = Color.Red;
            panel1.Controls.Add(panel2);
            Panel panel3 = new Panel();
            panel3.Top = 10;
            panel3.Left = 220;
            panel3.Width = 360;
            panel3.Height = 80;
            panel3.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            panel1.Controls.Add(panel3);

            DataGridView dgv1 = new DataGridView();
            dgv1.Left = 100;
            dgv1.Top = 200;
            dgv1.Width = 600;
            dgv1.Height = 300;
            this.Controls.Add(dgv1);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Col 1", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Col 2", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Col 3", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Col 4", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Col 5", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Col 6", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Col 7", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Col 8", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Col 9", typeof(string));



            dgv1.DataSource = dt;

            int count = 0;
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dgv1.Columns)
            {
                if (count < 3)
                {
                    col.Width = 60;
                }
                else
                {
                    col.Width = 40;
                }
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I knew I forgot the line but never had a chance to update.